# Need python-code to be translated into in Java

Tags: java, python-3.x

Python Code

```
            decoded = base64.b64decode(base64input)
            resultBytes = b""
            i = 0
            while i < len(decoded):
                    c = decoded[i + 0] * 256 + decoded[i + 1]
                    d = decoded[i + 2] * 256 + decoded[i + 3]
                    lenRead = 0

                    gzchunk = (bytes((31,139,8,0)) + decoded[i:i+c])
                    try:
                            with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(gzchunk)) as gf:
                                    while True:
                                            readSize = min(16384, d - lenRead)
                                            readBytes = gf.read(size=readSize)
                                            lenRead += len(readBytes)
                                            resultBytes += readBytes
                                            if len(readBytes) == 0 or (d - lenRead) <= 0:
                                                    break
                    except IOError as err:
                            pass # provide error message later

                    i += c + 4
```

i tried it with this Java Code, but it fails

```
            // read file-content into byte array
            byte[] decoded = null;
            try {
                decoded = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileReader(fullFilePath), org.apache.commons.codec.Charsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Decode
            byte[] fb = null;
            try {
                fb = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(decoded)).getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte[] resultBytes = null;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < fb.length) {
                int c = (fb[i + 0] * 256) + (fb[i + 1]);
                int d = (fb[i + 2] * 256) + (fb[i + 3]);
                int lenRead = 0;

                byte[] a1 = convert2ByteArray(new int[] { 31, 139, 9, 0 });
                byte[] a2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(fb, i, i + c);
                byte[] gzchunk = copyByteArray(a1, a2);

                GZIPInputStream gf = null;
                byte[] readBytes;
                int readSize;
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        readSize = Math.min(16384, (d - lenRead));
                        gf = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(gzchunk), readSize);
                        int read = gf.read();
                        readBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(read).array();
                        lenRead += readBytes.length;
                        resultBytes = copyByteArray(resultBytes, readBytes);
                        if (readBytes.length == 0 | (d - lenRead) <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i += c + 4;
            }
```

Thanks for your support

## Update:

#### 1. Different byte array values

More clarification on the failure. So, the for python

```
    print(fb[i + 0])
    print(fb[i + 1])
    print(fb[i + 2])
    print(fb[i + 4])
```

Output is:

```
30
208
234
120
```

with my Java code the output is:

```
30
-48
-22
96
```

#### 2. IllegalArgumentException

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: buffer size <= 0
```

on line

```
 gf = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(gzchunk), readSize);
```

## Update 2:

@Joop:

With your suggestion, I know have written the equivalent for the python code:

```
c = decoded[i + 0] * 256 + decoded[i + 1]
d = decoded[i + 2] * 256 + decoded[i + 3]
```

in java

```
int c= ((fb[i + 0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (fb[i + 1] & 0xFF);
int d= ((fb[i + 2] & 0xFF) << 8) + (fb[i + 3]);
```

But i still do receive different values for the same data:
Python:

```
c = 7888
d = 60000
```

Java:

```
c = 27375
d = 48829
```

## Update 3:

Basically what i try to do is:

1. Base-64 decode the whole thing. Then on the decoded bytes:
2. Compute the next compressed length from the first two bytes in big-endian order. Call it c.
3. Compute the next uncompressed length from the next two bytes in big-endian order. Call it u.
4. Use zlib to decode the zlib stream consisting of the next c bytes. Verify that zlib decoded exactly c bytes, and that the resulting uncompressed data is exactly u bytes long.
5. Repeat starting at step 2 until the data is consumed. (It should all be exactly consumed.)

Comment: "... but it fails", please clarify what the issue is with your code, any errors etc.

Comment: let's see the error

Comment: Well, you open the compressed stream in the inner loop... I think it should be opened outside of the inner loop, and closed after it...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto This maybe wrong, but the first error happens earlier

Answer (score 1):

*The error:* The type `byte` is signed and to prevent sign extension as an int has to be masked (`& 0xFF`).

```
int c = (fb[i + 0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (fb[i + 1] & 0xFF);
```

The signed byte is between -128 and 127, so `a1` could simply be written:

```
byte[] a1 = new byte[] { 31, (byte)139, 9, 0 };
```

Then you can use java to the fullest as:

```
        // read file-content into byte array
        Path path = Paths.get(fullFilePath);
        byte[] decoded = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        // Decode
        byte[] fb = Base64.getDecoder().decode(decoded);
```

I would catch the exceptions at a larger scope, as one has to stop on a larger scope, and it's easier.

The loop I did not check; that is something to simplify as soon it works.

---

***After more debug info in question:***

The debugging code

```
print(fb[i + 4])
```

should be

```
print(fb[i + 3])
```

`c` is now correct; java delivering -48 instead of 208 is caused by `byte` being signed: 256-48 = 208 and 256-22 = 234. For `d` a bit of old code still messes the sign extension.

```
int d = ((fb[i + 2] & 0xFF) << 8) | (fb[i + 3] & 0xFF);
```

I tried myself on simplifying the loopings, no guarantee.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i = 0;
    ByteBuffer inbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(fb);
    while (inbuf.hasRemaining()) {
        int c = inbuf.getShort() & 0xFFFF;
        int d = inbuf.getShort() & 0xFFFF;
        assert c <= inbuf.limit();

        byte[] gzchunk = new byte[4 + c];
        gzchunk[0] = 31;
        gzchunk[1] = (byte)139;
        gzchunk[2] = 9;
        gzchunk[3] = 0;
        inbuf.get(gzchunk, 4, c);

        byte[] readBytes = new byte[d];
        GZIPInputStream gf = new GZIPInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(gzchunk), d);
        int nread = gf.read(readBytes, 0, d);
        // No loop required as non-blocking ByteArrayInputStream.
        assert nread == d;
        out.write(readBytes);
        gf.close();

        i += 4 + c;
        assert inbuf.position() == i;
    }
    out.close();
    return out.toByteArray();
```

As there is no limit on 16K (python limit perhaps?), the reading becomes simpler. Instead of `read` one should use `readAllBytes` when java > 8. `read` can deliver a partial result on what is available. However a ByteArrayInputStream has all data available.

Using a ByteBuffer that by default has order `ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN` will allow `getShort` doing away with our calculation.

Comment: Thank you @Joop for this, but still i don't get the expeted valies. Please see my 2nd update

Comment: Added a correction, and after looking at the loop code, provided a simpler version, as I do not trust the code. Whether my code works I cannot entirely guarantee; it does things differently.

Comment: Thank You @Joop, but I get `java.nio.BufferUnderflowException` at `inbuf.get(gzchunk, 4, c);`. Please see my update 3, maybe this will clarify things

Comment: @jimmybondy I am afraid I thought I did just that, though what those pre-defined 4 bytes do prefixing the compressed content I do not know. Further it is up to you, debugging, comparing with python on test data. Good luck.